# html <select> tag multiple options, one checked, several others disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

In html, `<select multiple="multiple">` tag,  if one certain option checked, how to disable several "other relevant options"

example:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
   <option value=''></option>
    <option value='"matchCase": true'>matchCase</option>
    <option value='"matchWildCards": true'>matchWildCards</option>
    <option value='"ignoreSpace": true'>ignoreSpace</option>
    <option value='"ignorePunct": true'>ignorePunct</option>
    <option value='"matchWholeWord": true'>matchWholeWord</option>
    <option value='"matchSoundsLike": true'>matchSoundsLike</option>
    <option value='"matchPrefix": true'>matchPrefix</option>
    <option value='"matchSuffix": true'>matchSuffix</option>
</select>
```

In the above example

if `matchWildCards` option checked, `matchCase, matchPrefix, matchSuffix,matchWholeWord` options must be disabled,users can no longer check these four options if `matchWildCards` option checked. if users have checked these some of the above four options, those checked must also be unchecked.

Is it possible to do something like this purely in html? if not, javascript or Jquery related plugins are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need. Add classes to the options to simplify the filtering

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="20">
  <option value=''></option>
  <option value='"matchCase": true'>matchCase</option>

  <!-- note added class "no-match"-->
  <option class="no-match" value='"matchWildCards": true'>matchWildCards</option>

  <option value='"ignoreSpace": true'>ignoreSpace</option>
  <option value='"ignorePunct": true'>ignorePunct</option>
  <!-- note added class "match" -->
  <option class="match" value='"matchWholeWord": true'>matchWholeWord</option>
  <option class="match" value='"matchSoundsLike": true'>matchSoundsLike</option>
  <option class="match" value='"matchPrefix": true'>matchPrefix</option>
  <option class="match" value='"matchSuffix": true'>matchSuffix</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var $options = $(this).children()
  if ($options.filter('.no-match').is(':selected')) {
    $options.filter('.match').prop('selected', false).prop('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $options.filter('.match').prop('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

I'm not so sure that this UX won't confuse users though

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v56kved5/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: This UX is quite similar to the one for Microsoft Word 'Find and Replace' function, but Word uses checkbox, maybe I should also use checkbox instead of select.

Comment: might be better...then they can be grouped